# CRON Job with an R script giving a warning then execution haulted

Tags: r, terminal, cron, opensuse

I am trying to schedule a CRON job to run every day at the same hour. It appears from the logfile that the script is executing but it gets haulted due to not being able to find packages.

I have the following `crontab`

```
34 23 * * * echo "$(date) Log File" > /home/bscuser/Escritorio/testCRONOUPUT.txt
34 23 * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /home/myuser/Desktop/myProject/rscripts/myRScript.R 2> /tmp/cronerror
```

So at minute 34 of hour 23 it will execute the two CRON lines.

However, from the `cronerror` file I see the following:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: package "methods" in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
2: S3 methods ‘[.getAnywhere’, ‘[.news_db’, ‘[.roman’, ‘Ops.roman’, ‘Summary.roman’, ‘as.character.person’, ‘as.character.roman’, ‘as.person.default’, ‘as.personList.default’, ‘as.personList.person’, ‘close.txtProgressBar’, ‘edit.data.frame’, ‘edit.default’, ‘edit.matrix’, ‘edit.vignette’, ‘format.MethodsFunction’, ‘format.aspell’, ‘format.news_db’, ‘format.object_size’, ‘format.roman’, ‘getRcode.vignette’, ‘head.array’, ‘head.array’, ‘head.default’, ‘head.function’, ‘head.matrix’, ‘head.ftable’, ‘print.aspell’, ‘print.aspell_inspect_context’, ‘print.Bibtex’, ‘print.changedFiles’, ‘print.fileSnapshot’, ‘print.findLineNumResult’, ‘print.getAnywhere’, ‘print.help_files_with_topic’, ‘print.hsearch’, ‘print.hsearch_db’, ‘print.Latex’, ‘print.ls_str’, ‘print.MethodsFunction’, ‘print.news_db’, ‘print.object_size’, ‘print.packag [... truncated] 
3: package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
4: S3 methods ‘print.recordedplot’, ‘print.colorConverter’, ‘print.RGBcolorConverter’, ‘checkFont.default’, ‘checkFont.Type1Font’, ‘checkFont.CIDFont’, ‘matchEncoding.Type1Font’, ‘matchEncoding.CIDFont’, ‘as.raster.raster’, ‘as.raster.logical’, ‘as.raster.numeric’, ‘as.raster.character’, ‘as.raster.matrix’, ‘as.raster.array’, ‘as.matrix.raster’, ‘is.na.raster’, ‘anyNA.raster’, ‘[.raster’, ‘[<-.raster’, ‘Ops.raster’, ‘print.raster’, ‘prettyDate’, ‘prettyDate’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found 
5: package ‘grDevices’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
6: S3 methods ‘print.recordedplot’, ‘print.colorConverter’, ‘print.RGBcolorConverter’, ‘checkFont.default’, ‘checkFont.Type1Font’, ‘checkFont.CIDFont’, ‘matchEncoding.Type1Font’, ‘matchEncoding.CIDFont’, ‘as.raster.raster’, ‘as.raster.logical’, ‘as.raster.numeric’, ‘as.raster.character’, ‘as.raster.matrix’, ‘as.raster.array’, ‘as.matrix.raster’, ‘is.na.raster’, ‘anyNA.raster’, ‘[.raster’, ‘[<-.raster’, ‘Ops.raster’, ‘print.raster’, ‘prettyDate’, ‘prettyDate’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found 
7: package ‘graphics’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
8: S3 methods ‘print.recordedplot’, ‘print.colorConverter’, ‘print.RGBcolorConverter’, ‘checkFont.default’, ‘checkFont.Type1Font’, ‘checkFont.CIDFont’, ‘matchEncoding.Type1Font’, ‘matchEncoding.CIDFont’, ‘as.raster.raster’, ‘as.raster.logical’, ‘as.raster.numeric’, ‘as.raster.character’, ‘as.raster.matrix’, ‘as.raster.array’, ‘as.matrix.raster’, ‘is.na.raster’, ‘anyNA.raster’, ‘[.raster’, ‘[<-.raster’, ‘Ops.raster’, ‘print.raster’, ‘prettyDate’, ‘prettyDate’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found 
9: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
10: package ‘methods’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: cmpfun, cmpfile, loadcmp, compile, disassemble, enableJIT, compilePKGS, getCompilerOption, setCompilerOptions
Calls: getNamespace -> loadNamespace -> namespaceExport
Execution halted
```

However, this script works perfectly in my RStudio and I can also execute the script in the terminal without issue.

SessionInfo RStudio

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=ca_ES.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=ca_ES.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=ca_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=ca_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] netstat_0.1.2       futile.logger_1.4.3 RSelenium_1.7.9     xml2_1.3.3         
 [5] forcats_0.5.2       stringr_1.4.1       dplyr_1.0.10        purrr_0.3.4        
 [9] readr_2.1.2         tidyr_1.2.1         tibble_3.1.8        ggplot2_3.3.6      
[13] tidyverse_1.3.2     rvest_1.0.3
```

SessionInfo Terminal

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 15.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=ca_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=ca_ES.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=ca_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=ca_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0
```

EDIT:

New error:

```
── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.2 ──
✔ ggplot2 3.3.6      ✔ purrr   0.3.4 
✔ tibble  3.1.8      ✔ dplyr   1.0.10
✔ tidyr   1.2.1      ✔ stringr 1.4.1 
✔ readr   2.1.2      ✔ forcats 0.5.2 
── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter()         masks stats::filter()
✖ readr::guess_encoding() masks rvest::guess_encoding()
✖ dplyr::lag()            masks stats::lag()
Error in library(RSelenium) : there is no package called ‘RSelenium’
Execution halted
```

Comment: What does `R.home()` return for you in your RStudio session? Does it return `/usr/bin/R`?

Comment: In RStudio `"/opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/R"`.  In an RSession in the terminal I get `"/opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/R"`

Comment: Well you are using `/usr/bin/Rscript` in your cron path which probably points to a completely different install of R. What if you change it to `/opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/RScript`? Does that exist?

Comment: `/bin/sh: /opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/RScript: No such file or directory` is the output of the `cronerror`

Comment: If you do `ls /opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/` at the terminal, what is returned? Is there no Rscript program in there? How did you install this version of R?

Comment: Oh, it might be `/opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/R/bin/Rscript`. Hard to tell without access to the file system.

Comment: Just added `/opt/R/4.2.0/lib64/R/bin/Rscript` since that where the file is. Seems to run but I get a no package `RSelenium()` but its installed...

Comment: It's possible you installed that package in a personal lib path and not one where your your chron job user has access to. You can see where packages are installed to with `installed.packages()[,c("LibPath")]`. See if the RSelenium package is in a different place.